# Truncate a sum in order to speed up an algorithm (Big O)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity, truncation-error

Let $k\leq n$, I am looking to *truncate this sum* (with a *Big O* or *Little o*) in order to compute just few terms
$$
\sum^k_{i=1} (k-(i-1))^{p}\sqrt{y_i}
$$
where $y=(y_i)_{i\leq n}$ is a *bounded sequence*, and $p\in(-\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2})$.

I do not think it is possible to cut a part of this sum, since for $p$ in the above range, *the sum does not converge*.

I need to speed up an algorithm in order to compute a part of this sum (other ideas are welcome).

---

I think the idea start from the *harmonic/p-series* for $p\in (-\frac{1}{2},0)$.

In this case I think , $\int^n_1 x^p dx=(p+1)(n^{p+1}-1) \leq \sum^n_{i=1} i^p$

Comment: Possibly will be helpful https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0042

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38985/truncating-p-series